# Subclassing a class with required parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

If subclassing a "class" in JavaScript is done like so:

```
var ParentClass = function() {
    // something
};


var ChildClass = function() {
    // something
};

ChildClass.prototype = new ParentClass();
```

... what should I do when the parent class has required parameters?

```
var ParentClass = function(requiredParameter) {
    if (typeof requiredParameter === 'undefined') {
        throw new TypeError("'requiredParameter' is required!");
    }
};


var ChildClass = function() {
    // something
};

ChildClass.prototype = new ParentClass();
// ^ Throws TypeError
```

Thanks.

Comment: I use an "init" function and avoid "non-literal" prototypes (e.g. I use `.prototype = { .... }`. This is error, is of course, because `new ParentClass()` is eagerly invoked.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-static" prototypes? Do you mean redefining the methods for each new instance?

Comment: extend constructor functions by "cloning" their prototype, not by calling them. Clone objects by setting them as the constructor of a dummy function and invoking the function with `new`. See my (updated) answer.

Comment: @pst Neat, and interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclass it like this instead:

```
function clone (obj) {
  if (!obj) return;
  clone.prototype = obj;
  return new clone();
}

var ParentClass = function() {
    // something
};


var ChildClass = function() {
    // something
};

ChildClass.prototype = clone(ParentClass.prototype);
ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass; // if you want
```

Now you don't have to worry about it, because you don't have to call the parent constructor to subclass it :)

Comment: That `clone` function is broken. You forgot the line `var clone = function () {};`...

Comment: As we established below (in my answer), there is `Object.create` which gets that job done. A custom `clone` function is therefore not needed.

Comment: it works fine, i'll set up a jsfiddle if you want. As we established below Object.create is fairly recent, and this is a perfectly legitimate alternative and basically how it's been done for a long time.

Comment: This way is a sloppier. Each time you want to inherit you'll be forced to write the `.prototype = clone(parent.prototype)` and the constructor as well. My method also has the advantage of owning the super class via `uber`

Comment: Šime: http://jsfiddle.net/RsgJf/ ... Trevor, I agree that encapsulating all of this into some kind of 'inherit' function is cleaner. I'm just trying to keep things as close as possible to the original example.

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: @LeeGee correct, it dispels the false premise upon which the question was based and provides a better solution, just like all the other answers here.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using this method, even though it has "been accepted as the correct answer". Use the method described below by Šime Vidas. The motivation for saying this is given in https://kevhuang.com/subclasses-and-inheritance-in-javascript/

Answer (score 26):

This is how its done:

```
function Parent( a ) {
    this.a = a;
}

function Child( a, b ) {
    Parent.call( this, a ); // this is crucial
    this.b = b;
}

Child.prototype = Object.create( Parent.prototype );
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ECCgt/ (analyze the instances in the console)

---

The way you're doing it

```
ChildClass.prototype = new ParentClass();
```

is a dirty hack which is broken and should be avoided. Use `Object.create` to set up the inheritance relationship between the two prototype objects.

The second line

```
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

is somewhat optional. We are correcting the `constructor` property because we had to overwrite `Child.prototype` in order to set up the inheritance. If you don't care about the `constructor` property, just leave out that line.

Comment: Isn't Object.create fairly new?

Comment: It's part of ES5, so you'll need to implement it yourself for IE8 and under cases...or non updated browsers.

Comment: @user886931 No, its' 2 years old. You need the ES5 shim if you care about older browsers...

Comment: I guess we have different ideas of "fairly new" ;)

Comment: @user886931 It's irrelevant anyway. There is ES5 shim, so you can safely use `Object.create`. Case closed.

Comment: This is also a quite dirty hack as a matter of fact.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to inherit...

```
var inherit = (function () {
  var F = function () {}; // cache function
  return function (C, P) { // Accepts Constructor and Parent
    F.prototype = P.prototype;
    // faster prototype chain lookup than direct instantiation
    C.prototype = new F(); 
    C._super = P.prototype;
    C.prototype.constructor = C; // for checking instanceof
  };
}());
```

Comment: afaik it's safe to put F outside inherit, that way you can reuse the same function instead of creating a new one for each call to inherit. It might be a bit more efficient.

Comment: Why is that function in parens? It's not an immediately invoked function expression...

Comment: That's why I return a function instead of creating F each time it's used.

Comment: Without arguments? It accepts the `constructor` and the `parent`. @LeeGee